# Datasheet / footprint for this weird USB-C connector?

Tags: connector, identification, datasheet, surface-mount, usb-c

I've got this SMD USB-C type connector I want to use:

[image: Weird USB C Connector]

It has a **single row of 12 pins** along the back, presumably meaning the other 12 USB C pins are pre-connected internally. Neat. This also suggests it would be easier to solder, having only half the pins to deal with.

However, I can't find a datasheet or land pattern for this anywhere. I can find the two other (conventional) styles - the one where the second set of 12 pins is available, either as a secondary row underneath the body of the connector or as a set of mini through-hole pins (they call that one the "hybrid" pattern).

I have no details about this at all - no manufacturer name, and the store I bought it from has no idea (presumably they bought it in bulk from Asia). There are no identifying markings that could lead me in the right direction either.

Anyone have any clues?

Comment: This is why you don't buy anything without a datasheet. How should we know? Assuming there are many different pinouts, what should identify which is it? Get your multimeter, set it to continuity test and figure it out yourself.

Comment: Can you see contacts at the top and the bottom? Can you post a picture from the front of the connector?

Comment: You have mad skillz soldering? What's the pitch on that thing, 0.4mm pin-to-pin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

[image: USB C]

Interestingly, this connector is essentially just a USB 2 connector dressed up in USB 3 clothing. It drops access to the high-speed USB 3 ports, but has the mechanical advantage of having the reversible, much more reliable USB type C connector.

Comment: You should give credit for the stuff you post...........

Answer (score 0):

Your weird USB-C connector will **not** be conveniently interconnecting twelve pairs of contacts inside the connector body. That connector is most likely one that was designed for some specialty application such as a source connector on a charging device. The store where you bought it probably got a bucketful of the parts and are selling them to folks for a very low discount price.

A "to spec" USB-C connector for general application for any type of end (host, device or charger) will have 24 contacts. You should purchase from a legitimate supplier that offers to show data sheets for the parts that they sell so that you can make a proper determination of suitability to your application. Then when you make a selection you will have full design data available in order to properly design your device. Steer clear of any offering that does not provide direct access to layout information at least as detailed as this:

[image]

I checked at several popular online electronics components vendors and noted that there are a plethora of properly sourced USB-C type PCB mount connectors that come with data sheets. Typical offerings are available for reasonable prices even in quantity one at a couple of USD.